# Make data publicly searchable

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, kibana

I have a little hobby-project, where I scrape very special websites and store information in mongodb as well as in elasticsearch.

What I'd like to do is to provide others the possibility to search this data via a website (like a search engine for the data I have) but I don't really know how to do this. Can anybody suggest a good possibility on how to make this data searchable by everyone ?

Currently I use kibana and the ES api to search my data, but I think that it is a bit of a stupid idea to expose kibana to the internet (is there something like a stripped down kibana ??). 
If I just offer the possibility to run ES search commands (via an text input) I'd have to care about the presentation of the found events - I really hate web development and I'd like to avoid it as much as possible.

Thx a lot !

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly noticed ElasticSearch itself does not come with a search fronted and Kibana might indeed be a bit of overkill for your needs.

[This article](http://siddhumehta.blogspot.jp/2014/05/elasticsearch-tutorial-elasticsearch-gui-tools.html) lists some of the plugin options available for ElasticSearch (Elasticsearch GUI, Elastichead, Marvel, etc.) You might want to have a closer look at [Elasticsearch GUI](https://github.com/jettro/elasticsearch-gui), but this one also exposes some administration options.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Unfortunately I could not find any plugin that I would expose to the internet.